# combining ratios

Tags: functions

I am trying to work out how to blend compounds.

Compound 1 has 60% A and 15% B and 25% C
Compound 2 has 70% A and  5% B and 25% C

I want to make a new compound with 75% A and 10% B and 25% C

How much (what is the ratio) Compound 2 do I have to mix with Compound 1 to get the desired new compound.

Thanks so much.

Comment: I don't think you can!  Your percents don't add up to 100 in the new compound...

Comment: Fix your numbers for the new compund.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the new compound should have 65%A. Then things add up to 100% for the new compound, and also the goal 65% for A is between the percents of A in compounds 1 and 2.

For the numbers in the problem the C doesn't matter since it's the same in each of compounds 1,2.  You can then just pour the same amount of each of compounds 1,2 into a bucket and get the required result.

ADDED NOTE

In general the combination of $x$ amount of compound 1 with $y$ amount of compound 2, where $x+y=1$, produces $a_1x+a_2y$ percent for substance $A$, where compound 1 had $a_1$ percent of substance A, and compound 2 had $a_2$ percent of substance A. So to get a desired percent $a_3$ of substance $A$ in the mix, the desired percent $a_3$  must be somewhere between $a_1$ and $a_2$, otherwise it cannot be done.

If these conditions are met for the substance A, there are now already two equations on $x,y$ namely $x+y=1$ and $a_1x+a_2y=a_3.$ These two equations already determine $x,y$, so unless the original problem is rigged up correctly (as it was in my version of your problem, with 65% goal for A), there won't be a solution. The $x,y$ found so as to produce the right amount of A in the mix already give the resulting B and C as consequences, so that they cannot be prescribed arbitrarily independent of the desired percents for substance A.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful, but is there a formula I can use to work it out in every case?

Comment: @james Just added some explanation of what happens in general cases. Note it cannot always be done.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the same numbers as coffeemath in his answer, let me try another approach.

Since we look for the ratio $r$ of compound $2$ to compound $1$, let us consider $1$ unit of  compound $1$ and $r$ of compound $2$. So, we have $(1+r)$ units of compound $3$ the content of which being then $(60+70r)$ of product $A$ that we want to be $65$ in  compound $3$. This single information then leads to the equation $$\frac {60+70r}{1+r}=65$$ from which we can extract $r=1$. You can check that this leads to $10$ and $25$ for product $B$ and $C$.

You see that the problem is fixed by a single product (namely A in this case) and by chance you get the desired values for $B$ and $C$.

If you want to experience more difficult problems, start with three of more compounds.